# ¿Como quitar o ocultar la ruta de mi navegador cuando envió los datos por el router en angular4?

Tags: angular, angular5

html principal

```
<div>
        <a href="#" routerLink="/consulta/{{NewNumber}}/{{NewName}}/{{NewContrato}}/{{NewCuenta}}
        /{{NewDomicilio}}/{{NewNomina}}
        ">
        <button  class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!disabled" (click)="enviar($event)">CONSULAR EFECTO</button>

        </a>
 </div>
ts principal
//para recoger el objeto cuando pulso
metodo(event) {
        if(this.tableListado = !this.confirmF) {
             this.NewNumber = event.path[1].innerText;
            this.NewName = event.path[2].cells[7].innerText;
            this.NewNomina = event.path[2].cells[2].innerText;
            this.NewCuenta = event.path[2].cells[8].innerText;
            this.NewContrato = event.path[2].cells[5].innerText;
            this.NewDomicilio = event.path[2].cells[10].innerText;
}
}
cuando lo envio
 enviar(num: {}, nombre: {}, contrato: {}, cuenta: {}, direccion: {}, nomina:{}) {
            console.log("numberEnviar", this.NewNumber);

        //enviamos la id a consultas.component
        num = this.NewNumber
        nombre = this.NewName
        contrato = this.NewContrato;
        cuenta = this.NewCuenta;
        direccion = this.NewDomicilio;
        nomina = this.NewNomina
        this.router.navigate([`consulta/${num}/${nombre}/${contrato}/
                                ${cuenta}/${direccion}/${nomina}`]);
    }
ts-router
export const ROUTES: Routes = [

    { path: '', component: HeaderComponent },
    { path: 'listado', component: ListadoComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/header', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'consulta/:number/:librado/:contrato/:cuenta/:direccion/:nomina',
     component: ConsultaComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'header' }

];
ts secundario
listado():void {

// recodo los objetos
this.ruta.params.subscribe(params => {
    params['number'];
        this.identificador =  params['number'];
        this.NameLista = params['librado'];
        this.conttratoLista = params['contrato'];
        this.cuentaLista = params['cuenta'];
        this.domicilioLista = params['direccion'];
        this.nominaLista = params['nomina'];

})
```

html secundario, ejemplo:

```
<p>{{identificador }}</p>
```

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo he tenido situaciones parecidas, y si entendi bien usted quiere ocultar los detalles de la URL en el navegador. Si este es el caso intente este snippet:

```
 abreElemento() {
    this.router.navigate(['/consulta'], { 
      queryParams: { 
           number   : NewNumber, 
           librado  : NewName,
           contrato : NewContrato,
           cuenta   : NewCuenta,
           direccion: NewDomicilio,
           nomina   : NewNomina,
      } ,
      skipLocationChange: true
   });
  }
```

Nota: Recomendacion crear una interface que contenga todos los parametros y pasela en la ruta en vez de pasar los parametros independientes. (*Solo si es posible, no tengo toda la informacion*)

```
 <button  class="btn btn-danger" (click)="abreElemento()">Navegar </button>
```

Esto garantiza que su URL solo contiene lo basico en este caso **/consulta**

Espero esta idea resuelva su problema.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no está muy clara, pero uno de los problemas que veo es que quieres enviar datos desde un componente, para que sean procesados en otro, y has usado rutas para ello. En mi opinión esa no es una función de las rutas (en [este artículo](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-sistema-routing-angular.html) tienes una buena introducción al sistema de routing en Angular), por lo que deberías cambiar la estructura de tu programa.

En [este otro artículo](https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797) se encuentran varias opciones para pasar datos de un componente a otro. Por ejemplo, usando un servicio:

Componente principal: guardar los datos en un objeto y llamar al servicio

```
constructor(private consultaService: ConsultaService) {}

enviar(evento) {
    // Obtener las variables...
    datos = {
      num: num,
      contrato: contrato,
      // ...
    };
    this.consultaService.consulta(datos);
}
```

Servicio, ConsultaService.ts: emite el nuevo valor

```
@Injectable()
export class ConsultaService {
  @Output() consulta: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  consulta(datos) {
    this.consulta.emit(datos);
  }
}
```

Segundo componente: se subscribe al servicio

```
constructor(private consultaService: ConsultaService) {}

// En otra función
this.ConsultaService.consulta.subscribe(datos => {
  // Haz algo con los datos...
});
```

Nota: este código es una sugerencia para que mejores la estructura de tu aplicación, no lo he comprobado.

Más información: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service